# Should I call SaveChanges() in my repository or what should I do in case I absolutely have to call it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I've seen many examples where other developers suggest to not call `SaveChanges()` or `SaveChangesAsync()` in every function of a repository class which modifies something in the database because it would be much slower compared to only saving the changes at the very end. However, I keep running into problems with this approach because I often have to get the ID of a new entity in my repositories in order to do something else (like inserting into a different table). Therefore I do not see an alternative other than calling `SaveChanges()` in those cases. Does this mean that I should also be calling `SaveChanges()` in other repository functions for the sake of consistency, even if it is not required in all of them, or is there a better way to implement this? I do not want to constantly have to think if a function I am using already calls `SaveChanges()` or not, so I am not sure how to implement this in a way that is both efficient and also easy to work with for the developer. Right now I also have no way to manually call `SaveChanges()` from my service layer, so I really have no other option than calling it in the repositories.

Comment: Your DbContext is already both a repository and unit-of-work.  So what value does your extra repository layer create to offset the difficulties it is causing you?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The data for almost all of my entities is actually split across multiple tables in the database. For example, each entity also has a table named like <EntityName>_translations which contains translations of string properties such as the entity name in different languages. This is something I do not want to deal with in my service layer, so I abstract it away inside my repositories.

Comment: Is there a need not to call SaveChanges? Are you running into performance issues? Else don't preemptively optimize. Just call SaveChanges when you need an entity to be stored. Sure, there is some performance impact of calling it, but it's not that big. We call it all the time in our apps. If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: @JHBonarius Not yet as this project is not rolled out anywhere so far. However, it will be used by a potentially large userbase (at least larger than most projects I worked on before) so I have to consider anything that could impact the performance in a negative way.

Comment: Why not a seperate method in your repository for saving all changes that does little more than call `SaveChanges` on your `DbContext` in the background?

Comment: @404 Great suggestion! I actually just had the exact same idea and already implemented it :)

Comment: Then what question is left here? And why do you keep asking almost identical questions about transactions and repositories?

Comment: @Gert Arnold There is no question left here but there is also no answer which I could accept, or am I missing something? I keep asking similar questions because I've been trying to wrap my head around how to implement EF Core 6 properly in my project for days and the more time I spent on this the more questions came up in my mind where in many cases I couldn't find a precise answer for. They might seem identical but if you read through them carefully, they are not.